# Routerprefix not working in Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am trying to change the routerprefix in Azure Function sdk 3.0.5 using the following code in host.js

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "http": {
      "routePrefix": "v1"
    }
  }
}
```

When I run this in debug mode and the console app runs the functions apps still all appear with the /api/ in the path e.g.

```
GetObject: [GET] http://localhost:7071/api/object/{id:int}
```

Do I need to specify something in the functions.cs file?

Here is the log from the Azure Function console. If I open the referenced host.json file it shows the above code.

```
[11.3.2020 09:39:17] Building host: startup suppressed: 'False', configuration suppressed: 'False', startup operation id: 'HIDDEN'
[11.3.2020 09:39:17] Reading host configuration file 'C:\MyAzureFunctionApp\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\host.json'
[11.3.2020 09:39:17] Host configuration file read:
[11.3.2020 09:39:17] {
[11.3.2020 09:39:17]   "version": "2.0"
[11.3.2020 09:39:17] }
[11.3.2020 09:39:17] Reading functions metadata
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] 69 functions found
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] Loading startup extension 'Startup'
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] Loaded extension 'Startup' (1.0.0.0)
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] Initializing Warmup Extension.
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] Initializing Host. OperationId: 'HIDDEN'.
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] Host initialization: ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, OperationId=HIDDEN
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] LoggerFilterOptions
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] {
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "MinLevel": "None",
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "Rules": [
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]     {
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "ProviderName": null,
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "CategoryName": null,
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "LogLevel": null,
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]     },
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]     {
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "CategoryName": null,
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "LogLevel": "None",
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "Filter": null
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]     },
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]     {
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "ProviderName": "Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Diagnostics.SystemLoggerProvider",
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "CategoryName": null,
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "LogLevel": null,
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]       "Filter": "<AddFilter>b__0"
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]     }
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   ]
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] }
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] FunctionResultAggregatorOptions
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] {
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "BatchSize": 1000,
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "FlushTimeout": "00:00:30",
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "IsEnabled": true
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] }
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] SingletonOptions
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] {
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "LockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "ListenerLockPeriod": "00:00:15",
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "LockAcquisitionTimeout": "10675199.02:48:05.4775807",
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "LockAcquisitionPollingInterval": "00:00:05",
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "ListenerLockRecoveryPollingInterval": "00:01:00"
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] }
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] HttpOptions
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] {
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "DynamicThrottlesEnabled": false,
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "MaxConcurrentRequests": -1,
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "MaxOutstandingRequests": -1,
[11.3.2020 09:39:18]   "RoutePrefix": "api"
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] }
[11.3.2020 09:39:18] Starting JobHost
```

Comment: When you run you function what's the setting `RoutePrefix` in the stack log?

Comment: Hi @GeorgeChen please see the updated question with the log. The RoutePrefix shows api even though the loaded file contains custom prefix.

Comment: And you have set the `CopyToOutputDirectory` in rickvdbosch  answer?

Comment: Yes, it was already there!

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the `routePrefix` in the host.json file the way you did in your example should be enough. I tested this locally and it works fine in both V2 and V3 Function apps.

Make sure the entry for your host.json file in the csproj file looks as follows:

```
<None Update="host.json">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
</None>
```

If that is OK, please follow these steps to try and fix the issue:

- Clean the solution (Visual Studio -> Build -> Clean solution)
- Close Visual Studio
- Delete the `bin` and `obj` folder from the project root folder
- Open the solution and run the Function again

Comment: Hi @rickvdbosch I tried those things without luck. In case it will help I added the console output to the question.